# Creating Pandas 2d heatmap based on accumulated values (rather than actual frequency)?

Tags: python, pandas, frequency, heatmap

Thanks for reading, I've spent 3-4 hours searching for examples to solve this but can't find any that solve.. the ones I did try didn't seem to work with pandas DataFrame object.. any help would be very much appreciated!!:)

Ok this is my problem.

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing 12 columns.
I have 500,000 rows of data.

Most of the columns are useless. The variables/columns I am interested in are called:  x,y and profit

Many of the x and y points are the same,
so i'd like to group them into a unique combination then add up all the profit for each unique combination.

Each unique combination is a bin (like a bin used in histograms)

Then I'd like to plot a 2d chart/heatmap etc of x,y for each bin and the colour to be total profit.

e.g.

x,y,profit

7,4,230.0

7,5,162.4

6,8,19.3

7,4,-11.6

7,4,180.2

7,5,15.7

4,3,121.0

7,4,1162.8

Note how  values  x=7, y=4, there are 3 rows that meet this criteria..  well the total profit should be:
230.0 - 11.6 +1162.8 = 1381.2
So in bin x=7, y = 4, the profit is 1381.2

Note for values x=7, y=5, there are 2 instances.. total profit should be: 162.4 + 15.7 = 178.1
So in bin x=7, y = 5, the profit is 178.1

So finally, I just want to be able to plot: x,y,total_profit_of_bin

e.g. To help illustrate what I'm looking for, I found this on internet, it is similar to what I'd like, (ignore the axis & numbers)

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-F8q_ZcI-HJg/T4_l7D0C7yI/AAAAAAAAAgE/Bqtx3eIHzRk/s1600/heatmap.jpg

Thank-you so much for taking the time to read:)

Comment: But x and y probably won't have the same number of bins right? How would that look on a graph? missing values, how would you even represent that? What does each tick on the graph represent? Surely you would want bins of equal size right? The reason I ask, is because what you want to do would be easy with groupby passing a function, but you can't aggregate this data into bins of equal length. You could separate them out, but then I still don't really see how that would work on a graph.

Answer (score 0):

If for 'bin' of x where the values are x are equal, and the values of y are equal, then you can use groupby.agg. That would look something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = YourData

AggDF = df.groupby('x').agg({'y' : 'max', 'profit' : 'sum'})

AggDF
```

That would get you the data I think you want, then you could plot as you see fit. Do you need assistance with that also?

NB this is only going to work in the way you want it to if within each 'bin' i.e. the data grouped according to the values of x, the values of y are equal. I assume this must be the case, as otherwise I don't think it would make much sense to be trying to graph x and y together.

Comment: Hi, thank-you for your quick reply.. ALMOST perfect!!   I tested this on a sample of data, the Y-values are great. eg there may be several X with the same Y values. But the problem is, the X-values are unique and never repeated. e.g. the x goes from 1 to 350 linerally.. in actually fact there could be eg x=50,y=62.2  and x=50, y=84.16 .. but this information has dissapeared.  p.s. if you could help with plot as well would be amazing.. I'm going thro the Pandas book by O'Reilly as we speak, this plot seems out of the scope of the book. Thanks so much

Comment: So within the group you mention where x = 50 what value of y do you want to aggregate to? The problem is I think that the way you have set up the problem does not make sense. You dont want one graph, you want two. One plotting the x bins of profit, one plotting y. Is that right? You can't do both at the same time as the bins are different clearly. make sense?

Comment: Hi,  hmm.. maybe I didn't explain so clearly :)  ok in the example above, at position (7,4), the value of the profit z (or the color of plot) is  1381.2   and at position(7,5) value of z (profit) is 178.1.. there could also be a (6,4) and a (6,5) with different profit values.. I just want to take x&y and find unique pairs. Then the profit for the unique pairs. At the end of the day I just have a list of the unique x&y pairs, and the total profit associated with them.  eg (2,4) is different than (4,2) etc

Comment: AggDF = df.groupby(['x', 'y'']).agg({'profit' : 'sum'}) - right?

Comment: Looking brilliant thank-you! I'm learning Pandas but hadn't got to learning about this.. thanks so much..! You saved me a whole lode of time and I also know what to read up on next :)

Comment: glad i could help. actually i have a whole notebook about using groupby, i may post it. You can vote for my answer if you care to.

Comment: Hi Woody, I already tried to vote up your reply but it says I must have a feedback of 15 or something..  here's the deal mate, can you vote up my question, I'll keep asking questions, then when I have a feedback of 15 (maybe in a couple of months), I'll big up all your replies ! so delayed reward!

Comment: P.s. that notebook would be real helpful, do you have a link I could click on ?!